# Problems with references to equations

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, cleveref

I am trying to write macros to render several types of references, and the work properly for everything but equations. `\namecref{eq:1}` gives me "??" instead of equation and `\nameref{eq:1}` gives me the description of the enclosing environment instead of a null string. The document below has my macros and sample text showing the problems.

```
   \documentclass{amsart}

   \usepackage{ifthen}

   % This should be the last package
   \usepackage [colorlinks] {hyperref}
   \usepackage{cleveref}

   \newcommand \fullref [1]
      { \ifthenelse {\equal{\nameref{#1}}{}}
          {\cref{#1}}
          {\cref{#1} (\nameref{#1})}
      }

   \newcommand \fullrefrange [2]
      {\namecrefs{#1}
        \ifthenelse {\equal{\nameref{#1}}{}}
          {\ref{#1}}
          {\ref{#1} (\nameref{#1})}
        to
        \ifthenelse {\equal{\nameref{#2}}{}}
          {\ref{#2}}
          {\ref{#2} (\nameref{#2})}
      }

   \newcommand \Pageref [1]
      { \ifthenelse {\equal{\nameref{#1}}{}}
          {\cref{#1} on p.~\pageref{#1}}
          {\cref{#1} (\nameref{#1}) on p.~\pageref{#1}}
      }

   \newcommand \refrange [2]
     {
       \ref{#1}
       to
       \ref{2}
     }

   \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
   \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

   \theoremstyle{definition}
   \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
   \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
   \newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
   \newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Exercise}

   \theoremstyle{remark}
   \newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

   \numberwithin{equation}{section}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{definition}[A definition]
   \label{def:1}
   This is a definition.
   \end{definition}

   \begin{lemma}[A lemma]
   \label{lem:1}
   This is a lemma.
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item
   \label{it:rishon}
   first
   \item
   \label{it:sheini}
   second
   \end{enumerate}
   \end{lemma}

   \begin{corollary}[A corollary]
   \label{cor:1}
   This is a corollary.
   \end{corollary}

   \begin{corollary}[Another corollary]
   \label{cor:2}
   This is  another corollary.
   \end{corollary}

   \begin{theorem}[A theorem]
   \label{thm:1}
   This is a theorem.
   \begin{subequations}
   \begin{equation}
   \label{eq:1}
   first
   \end{equation}
   \begin{equation}
   \label{eq:2}
   second
   \end{equation}
   \end{subequations}
   \end{theorem}

   \begin{flushleft}
   autoref\{cor:1\} = \autoref{cor:1} \\
   cref\{cor:1\} = \cref{cor:1} \\
   crefrange\{cor:1\}\{cor:2\} = \crefrange{cor:1}{cor:2} \\
   fullrefrange\{cor:1\}\{cor:2\} = \fullrefrange{cor:1}{cor:2}
   \end{flushleft}

   \begin{flushleft}
   autoref\{def:1\} = \autoref{def:1} \\
   cref\{def:1\} = \cref{def:1} \\
   fullref\{def:1\} = \fullref{def:1} \\
   namecref\{def:1\} = \namecref{def:1} \\
   namecrefs\{def:1\} = \namecrefs{def:1}
   \end{flushleft}

   \begin{flushleft}
   crefrange\{eq:1\}\{eq:2\} = \crefrange{eq:1}{eq:2} \\
   fullref\{eq:1\} = \fullref{eq:1} \\
   fullrefrange\{eq:1\}\{eq:2\} = \fullrefrange{eq:1}{eq:2} \\
   labelcref\{eq:1\} = \labelcref{eq:1} \\
   namecref\{eq:1\} = \namecref{eq:1} \\
   namecrefs\{eq:1\} = \namecrefs{eq:1} \\
   nameref\{eq:1\} = \nameref{eq:1}
   \end{flushleft}

   \begin{flushleft}
   autoref\{it:sheini\} = \autoref{it:sheini} \\
   cref\{it:sheini\} = \cref{it:sheini} \\
   cref\{it:rishon,it:sheini\} = \cref{it:rishon,it:sheini} \\
   crefrange\{it:rishon\}\{it:sheini\} = \crefrange{it:rishon}{it:sheini} \\
   labelcref\{it:rishon\} = \labelcref{it:rishon}
   \end{flushleft}

   \begin{flushleft}
   autoref\{lem:1\} = \autoref{lem:1} \\
   cref\{lem:1\} = \cref{lem:1} \\
   Pageref\{lem:1\} = \Pageref{lem:1}
   \end{flushleft}

   \begin{flushleft}
   autoref\{thm:1\} = \autoref{thm:1} \\
   cref\{thm:1\} = \cref{thm:1}
   \end{flushleft}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: Is the document class `tran-l` available online somewhere?

Comment: trans-l is from AMS; I'll have to check wither document works.

Comment: (almost) any of the ams article-style document classes will get the same result if you replace the document class by `amsart`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the instructions

```
\crefname{equation}{equation}{equations}
\crefname{subequation}{equation}{equations}
```

after loading the `cleveref` package.

It's not necessary to do so for the theorem-like environments as `cleveref` is clever enough (sorry, couldn't resist the pun) to determine the "names" of the `theorem`, `lemma`, `definition`, etc environments from the various `\newtheorem` instructions. Since no such setup is going on for the `equation` and `subequation` environments, you need to provide the required pieces of the information via `\crefname` instructions.

An MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or: "amsart"
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath} % not required if "amsart" document class is used

% These should be the last two packages to be loaded:
\usepackage [colorlinks] {hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% Further setup instructions
\crefname{equation}{equation}{equations}
\crefname{subequation}{equation}{equations}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

% Custom cross-referencing macros
\newcommand \fullref [1]
{ 
  \ifthenelse {\equal{\nameref{#1}}{}}{\cref{#1}}{\cref{#1} (\nameref{#1})}
}
\newcommand \fullrefrange [2]
{\namecrefs{#1}
  \ifthenelse {\equal{\nameref{#1}}{}}{\ref{#1}}{\ref{#1} (\nameref{#1})}
  to
  \ifthenelse {\equal{\nameref{#2}}{}}{\ref{#2}}{\ref{#2} (\nameref{#2})}
}
\newcommand \Pageref [1]
{ \ifthenelse {\equal{\nameref{#1}}{}}
  {\cref{#1} on p.~\pageref{#1}}{\cref{#1} (\nameref{#1}) on p.~\pageref{#1}}
}
\newcommand \refrange [2]{\ref{#1} to \ref{2}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}

\begin{theorem}[A theorem] \label{thm:1}
This is a theorem.
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{equation}\label{eq:1} \textnormal{first} \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}\label{eq:2} \textnormal{second}\end{equation}
\end{subequations}
\end{theorem}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
\verb+\crefrange{eq:1}{eq:2}+& \crefrange{eq:1}{eq:2} \\
\verb+\fullref{eq:1}+        & \fullref{eq:1} \\
\verb+\fullrefrange{eq:1}{eq:2}+& \fullrefrange{eq:1}{eq:2}\\
\verb+\labelcref{eq:1}+      & \labelcref{eq:1} \\
\verb+\namecref{eq:1}+       & \namecref{eq:1} \\
\verb+\namecrefs{eq:1}+      & \namecrefs{eq:1} \\
\verb+\nameref{eq:1}+        & \nameref{eq:1}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know `equation` is  known for `cleveref`, I am unsure about `subequation` however.

Comment: Semantically speaking, I don't see why `subequation` should be taken care of. It's never used by itself, and no one ever mentions  a `subequation`: it's only an equation with a special numbering.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Give the OP's code a try with and without the two `\crefname` instructions...

Comment: @Bernard - I've added an MWE (basically, a slimmed-down version of the OP's code). Without the `\crefname` instructions, one gets `??` in three instances.

Comment: @Mico: I replaced this obscure `trans-l` with `amsart` class and `cleveref` complains about `subequation` -- but I was not sure about that whether that is given by `cleveref` at all (apparently it isn't). But your document does not need the `equation` setup for `cleveref`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Thanks. I've posted an MWE in the meantime. AFAICT, there's no difference with regard to the cross-referencing issues if either `article` or `amsart` is employed.

Comment: When you added those two lines it fixed one of the problems but not the other. It is still rendering the description of the enclosing environment, e.g., "A theorem", instead of a null string. As a side note, changing trans-l to article, removing the theoremstyle  and adding amsmath also lets the document compile.

Comment: @shmuel - I'm afraid I don't have access to the `trans-l` document class, so I can't tell you what's causing the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: @Mico -- substitute `amsart` for `tran-l.  the only difference between them is that `tran-l` adds a logo with the journal name, an issn, and copyright info.  nothing else.  `amsart` is the key actor here.